# Replacing "and" by "&" (ampersand) for \parencite in authoryear-icomp

Tags: biblatex, ampersand, authoryear-icomp

I currently use the `authoryear-icomp` style with the `biblatex` package. By default, the citations are done as follows:

- using `\citeauthor{Butler.2012}`: Butler and Ekdahl
- using `\parencite{Butler.2012}`: (Butler and Ekdahl, 2012)
- within in the bibliography: Butler, Nancy Evelyn and Elizabeth Muriel Ekdahl (2012) [...]

Is it possible to adjust the style so that `\parencite{Butler.2012}` produces "(Butler & Ekdahl, 2012)", while the other citing styles still use the word "and" instead of an ampersand?

I tried redefining the `and` keyword:

```
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{
    and = {\&}            
}
```

But this of course leads to the case where *all* "and"s are replaced by "&".

**Edit:** Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[backend=biber,%
style=authoryear-icomp,%
natbib=true,%
hyperref=true,%
useprefix=true,%
minnames=1,%
maxnames=2]{biblatex}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{ %
    and = {\&}%
}

\addbibresource{testbib.bib}

\begin{document}
\citeauthor{Butler.2012}

\parencite[5]{Butler.2012}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Using the bibliography file `testbib.bib`:

```
@book{Butler.2012,
 author = {Butler, Nancy Evelyn and Ekdahl, Elizabeth Muriel},
 year = {2012},
 title = {{Aprenda Terena Vol. 1}},
 url = {https://www.sil.org/resources/archives/75521},
 urldate = {2022-02-24},
 edition = {Edição Online},
 publisher = {{Associação Internacional de Linguística – SIL Brasil} and {SIL International}},
 origdate = {1979},
 location = {Anápolis, GO},
 organization = {{Associação Internacional de Linguística – SIL Brasil}},
 editor = {Bridgeman, Loraine Irene}
}
```

Comment: Please, add a minimal example of code.

Comment: @egreg Added MWE!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use that `finalnamedelim` (the delimiter inserted between the last two names in a name list) is context sensitive and thus can get different definitions for `\parencite` and everywhere else.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[backend=biber,
  style=authoryear-icomp,
  natbib=true,
  useprefix=true,
  minnames=1,
  maxnames=2]{biblatex}

\DeclareDelimFormat[parencite]{finalnamedelim}{\addspace\&\space}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\citeauthor{sigfridsson}

\parencite[5]{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Sigfridsson and Ryde (Sigfridsson & Ryde, 1998, p. 5) Sigfridsson, Emma and Ulf Ryde (1998).]