Citing two authors with & instead of et al
I would like biblatex to write Author1 & Buthor2 (2024) when I have a reference with exactly two authors. Currently it writes Author1 et al. (2024). It is important to me that this only happens if there are exactly two authors. For a single author it should remain Author1 (2024) and for 3 or more authors Author1 et al. (2024).
This is my current code:
 \usepackage[backend=biber,
  style=authoryear-comp,
  sorting=nyt,
  natbib=true,
  useprefix=true,
  minnames=1,
  maxnames=1,
  uniquename=init,
  uniquelist=false,
  dashed=false,
  date=year,
  maxbibnames=99, %https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1554/biblatex-displaying-all-authors-of-multi-author-works-in-the-bibliography
  giveninits=true]{biblatex}
  \setlength\bibitemsep{1.5\itemsep}


You are forcing et al by   maxnames=1,  so not allowing 2 names

Ah, right. I changed it at some point because it would print 3 names instead of only one. Changed it and works great. One more question: Any option to change "and" to "&" for two names, or is the only way to change some .bst file?

Probably is, there are lots of options:-), i don't know biblatex that well, but someone will no doubt answer.

Alright. Thank you for the help. I appreciate it.

Off-topic: Setting the option minnames=1 can't possibly do anything useful. I'd get rid of it.

@Mico minnames=1 is preset, so setting it explicitly again indeed does not do anything useful here. But if something else (another style, ...) sets minnames to a different value, minnames=1 will definitely do something useful.

@moewe - Thanks for providing this clarification. :-)

As pointed out by David, I should have used maxnames=2 instead of maxnames=1.
For my question on "&" instead:
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/636380/replacing-and-by-ampersand-for-parencite-in-authoryear-icomp
% textcite is the equivalent to \citet
\DeclareDelimFormat[textcite]{finalnamedelim}{\addspace\&\space}


If you want to change this for all citations and not just \textcite, you can use \DeclareDelimFormat{finalnamedelim}{\addspace\&\space} without the optional argument, though you may or may not have a different definition for the bibliography, in which case you may need something like \DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{finalnamedelim}{\ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{2}{\finalandcomma}{}\addspace\bibstring{and}\space} to restore the old behaviour.
